# In selector with asterisk * not working in report selection

Tags: crystal-reports

What is the proper way to search a table for every record that starts in a similar way? I have tried:

```
"THESE. WORDS" IN {example_one.job_title} and {example_two.status} = "A"
```

But I need all combinations, including `"THESE. WORDS*"` Adding the asterisk doesn't work, I guess because of how `IN` works.

Comment: rather than use = , you can use like same as db side we use.

Comment: do you want to limit `job_title` by the list of values in `these. words`?  If so, you need your field on the left hand side and the values on the right.

Comment: so like "THESE. WORDS" IN {example_one.job_title} and {example_two.status} = "A"

Comment: yes @Beth yes I want to limit job titles so you're saying it just needs to be written backwards? {example_one.job_title} IN "THESE. WORDS" but how does that account for all variations beginning with "THESE. WORDS" like "THESE. WORDS. AGAIN" and "THESE. WORDS. ON. HOLD" ??

Comment: there are various job titles that all begin with the same 2 words and I want to include them all and pull them from the table of workers. for some reason in the select expert I can use an asterisk and it finds all combinations but in the formula section the asterisk doesn't work. There are other reasons why I need it in the formula section instead of the select expert. If I do it in select expert then it omits records that dont have those jobs and I still need the record to be pulled and just be blank so that another formula can add "does not exist" to the blank file

Comment: what you may want is `{example_one.job_title} LIKE 'keyword*'`

Comment: yes thank you @Beth so I guess the IN function just looks for exact matches because including a * doesn't work with IN but it does work with LIKE. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

To summarize information in the comments,

*to limit* `job_title` *by the list of values in* `these. words`*, you need your field on the left hand side and the values on the right.*

*you may want* `{example_one.job_title} LIKE 'keyword*'`

If you found this information helpful, you can upvote and/or accept the answer.

Comment: I don't feel like this answers the question because the problem had nothing to do with what side things are on. What it came down to was not the sides, but the functions LIKE vs IN, and how they handle asterisks differently. You can't use an asterisk with IN but you can with LIKE. This is the crucial point here. For example changing sides and still trying to use IN with an asterisk won't work. So this answer can mislead people if it doesn't mention the differences between LIKE and IN and how they handle asterisks.